# Convert all values into a single string in a multi-dimension PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'first_name' => 'testOne',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 333,
        'first_name' => 'test333',
    )
);
```

**Required Output:**

```
array("1_testOne","333_test333");
```

Comment: At least show some efforts.

Comment: I suggest looking into [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

Comment: Thank you for the response. I did this using for loop. Thanks, @Nick.

Answer (score 1):

This should help -

```
array_map(function($a) {
    return implode('_', $a); // implode all with '_'
}, $array);
```

[array_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(
             array(
                'id' => 1,
                'first_name' => 'testOne',
             ),
             array(
                'id' => 333,
                 'first_name' => 'test333',
             )
         );

$new_array = [];

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
   $new_array[] = $value['id'] . "_" . $value['first_name'];

}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new_array);
```

It will return output as

```
Array('1_testOne', '333_test333')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.